# Adding Google Maps (API V3) support to a Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, google-maps

I'm searching for a good solution for integrating google maps into a ruby on rails 2.3 app. I know there's a project called ym4r but it seems old and not so maintained. Should I use directly the Google API itself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fyi, I've just released a new version of gmaps4rails.

It's based on Rails 3 and uses Google maps API V3:

https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, I have used an API like [Geokit](http://geokit.rubyforge.org/) to geocode the data, but when it comes to building the map, use the JavaScript API directly. It gives you the most control and allows you to build the map exactly how you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out cartographer plugin, it supports painless integration of google maps v3 in rails , http://grati.la/cartorbflw

Answer (score 0):

you could try the [Geocoder](http://railscasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder) gem for a Rails application.